# Chrome app : Call remote PHP cause Content Security Policy error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I created a Chrome app, and i need to call an external PHP file to check a couple login/password in external database.

When i execute my ajax query, i get this error:

> jquery-1.12.4.js:10437 Refused to load the script
>   'https://.../userStandalone.php?callback=jQuery…2054696110&login=test&password=test&_=1472054696111'
>   because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:
>   "default-src 'self' blob: filesystem: chrome-extension-resource:".
>   Note that 'script-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is
>   used as a fallback.

```
$.ajax({
                url : https://IP/userStandalone.php',
                type : "GET",
                crossDomain : true,
                cache : false,
                data: {
                    login:"test",
                    password:"test"
                },
                dataType : "jsonp",
                success : function(json)
                {
                    var status = json.status;
                    if(status == "NOK")
                    {
                        cb('error');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cb('true');
                    }
                },
                error : function error(jsonError, ts,et)
                {
                    ajaxError(jsonError, ts,et,cb);
                }
            });
```

What can i do to fix it ?

Comment: The error message you posted basically tells you what the problem is. A google search of the last part of that message would've told you why you're getting that error, and how you can solve it

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Sorry, but i didn't find any trick code to fix my problem. If you find a trick, could you post it ?